# quick function proof

Tags: functions

If $f(x)$ is a function with unit area, show that the scaled and stretched function $\frac{1}{a}f(\frac{x}{a})$ also has unit area.

Before you give an answer I would still like to try to prove it myself. So to do this I suppose I need to know the definition of $f(x)$ having a unit area. How would that be expressed?

also how do I get the Tex formatting into my passage "like here for example" without having to make line breaks?

Comment: To insert Tex formatting without line breaks use a single dollar sign, instead of a double. A function with "unit area" means that the area under the curve is equal to 1.

Answer (score 2):

The definition I know is : $f$ have a unit area if and only if :
$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(x)dx=1 $$

and the question becomes a question of integration which can be done by substitution $u=\frac{x}{a}$

Comment: Or, maybe "unit area" means $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} |f(x)|\;dx = 1$.  Anyway the fact to be proved works with both of these definitions.

Answer (score 0):

we know $$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(x)dx=1 $$, make a substitution $ u=\dfrac{x}{a}$ so you have: $\\ $ $\dfrac{du}{dx}=\dfrac{1}{a} \Rightarrow dx=adu \Rightarrow \dfrac{1}{a}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(\dfrac{x}{a})dx= \dfrac{1}{a} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}af(u)du=\dfrac{1}{a}\times a\times\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(u)du=1 $